# Java constructor without name?

Tags: java, constructor

When I run the below code I am getting output as:

```
static block
TEst block
main block
```

How does the string "TEst block" gets printed? Is it considered as constructor?

```
public class TestBlk {

static {
    System.out.println("static block");
}

{
    System.out.println("TEst block");
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    TestBlk blk=new TestBlk();
    System.out.println("main block");

}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an *instance initialiser*, together with an default constructor.

A class without an explicit constructor, is given a synthetic, public, no-args constructor.

Constructors without a call to `this()` or `super()` (possibly with arguments) are given an implicit call to `super()` (without arguments, possibly something odd happens with inner classes).

Immediately after an implicit or explicit call to `super()`, all the code in field initialisers and instance initialisers gets inserted in the order it appears in the source code.

So after javac has finished with your code it looks a little like:

```
public class TestBlk {

    static {
        System.out.println("static block");
    }

    public TestBlk() {
        // Call constructor of java.lang.Object.
        super();

        // From instance (and field)initialiser.
        System.out.println("TEst block");

        // Rest of constructor:
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestBlk blk = new TestBlk();
        System.out.println("main block");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have here is called: initialization block.

> An initialization block is a block of
>   code between braces that is executed
>   before the object of the class is
>   created.

There are two types of initialization blocks:

1. **Non static** initialization block.

   `{
           System.out.println("TEst block");
    }`
2. **Static** initialization block.

   `static 
   {
       System.out.println("static block");
   }`

More specific, I like the explanation from [here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1254):

> Note that any initialization block
>   present in the class ***is executed
>   before the constructor***.
>
> So now the question comes why we need
>   **constructors** if we have **initialization blocks**. The answer is we don't need the default
>   constructor but **initialization block
>   cannot be parameterized** and so you
>   cannot have objects taking values from
>   out side and so initialization block
>   is not a substitute for constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is called as a part of object construction when you call `new TestBlk()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    System.out.println("TEst block");
}
```

That's an initialization block. See my [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556311/simple-java-new-concept-question/5556340#5556340).